# WatiN: Error opening Internet Explorer

Tags: c#-4.0, watin

I have a C# (Visual Studio 2010) project that opens Internet Explorer 8 like this:

```
Brower browser = new WatiN.Core.IE( "http://google.com");
```

This used to work, but I had some problems that required me to reinstall Internet Explorer (I am on Window 7). I am using the .NET 4.0 framework (although I have tried changing).

Now, I get this exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80080005 Server execution failed
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005
>   (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

I can open Internet Explorer manually, fine.

I am using Watin 2.0 (I have also tried 2.1).

Comment: How did you "re-install Internet Explorer"?

Comment: Control Panel...Uninstall or change a program...View Installed Updates... <-- It is a weird place, but somewhere in there was "Internet Explorer" and I removed it. Then found it again on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched project from "Any CPU" to "x86" and this problem went away. I am on a 64-bit CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try?

Browser browser = new WatiN.Core.IE.GoTo( "http://google.com");

GoTo is an existing method of WatiN

Cheers.

Comment: No. I did no see a "Goto" method on that class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to a Malware software that blocked the execution on my Windows. Once I close the app QQPCTray.exe, IE browser will launch and run successfully.

You can try to shutdown any detection software that may be running and try again.

Try running the app on a fresh Windows environment.